# Maven: JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar as dependency

Tags: java, maven, jarsigner, tools.jar

Im new to Maven. I must use class `sun.security.tools.JarSigner` in my project.Im trying add tools.jar as dependency.I proceeded by [Maven's FAQ](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#tools-jar-dependency), other articles from stackowerflow and google but without some positive results.

My NetBean can "see" JarSigner class wit pom beloow.

I can compile project without error or warn but I cant run it.

`pom.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>Experiments</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default-tools.jar</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>java.vendor</name>
                <value>Sun Microsystems Inc.</value>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
                <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

log after `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.mycompany.Main"`

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Experiments 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) @ Experiments ---
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/tools/JarSigner
    at com.mycompany.experiments.Main.main(Main.java:8)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.tools.JarSigner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 7 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.217s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Aug 22 18:04:28 CEST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project Experiments: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: sun/security/tools/JarSigner: sun.security.tools.JarSigner -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:java (default-cli) on project Experiments: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/tools/JarSigner
    at com.mycompany.experiments.Main.main(Main.java:8)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.security.tools.JarSigner
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 7 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Can you please specify your JAVA_HOME variable's value ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `<systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>` to `<systemPath>${java.home}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>`.

By the way, are you aware you are making a separation by the JDK version ? the `default-tools.jar` profile will be activated for jdk 1.6 and below (according to the `java.vendor` property) and since I see you are using jdk 7, I guess this is redundant.

Comment: I defined `<java.home>/opt/jdk1.7.0_67</java.home>` and use `<systemPath>${java.home}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>` steel same result.

Comment: I would have try to remove the <profiles> section and put <version>1.7.0_67</version> to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: I extract package `sun.security.tools` from `tools.jar` and this compiled sources copy to `src` folder. At compile phase I copy compiled classes into `target`.

```
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.7</version>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>copy-resources</id>
                      <phase>compile</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/sun/security/tools</outputDirectory>
                          <resources>          
                              <resource>
                                  <filtering>false</filtering>
                                  <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/sun/security/tools/</directory>
                                  <includes>
                                      <include>*.class</include>
                                  </includes>
                              </resource>
                          </resources>              
                      </configuration>            
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
```